# get years, months, days from number of days on android

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I want to get age in format years, months, and days; like this, `x years and y months and z days`.

I was able to get days with this:

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (dob_yr, dob_mt, dob_dy);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
Days nm_days = Days.daysBetween(birthdate, now);
```

I tried using `Log.d("days ", nm_days.getDays() +"");` and this is what I got: `10365`
How can I convert days to years months and days format?

**EDIT**

Ok. now I get something, but still doesn't really solve my problem, here it is:

```
Days a = Days.daysBetween(birthdate, now);
Months b = Months.monthsBetween(birthdate, now);
Years c = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);

Period g = new Period(b);
PeriodFormatter dhm = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYears()
    .appendSuffix(" years", " years")
    .appendSeparator(" and ")
    .appendMonths()
    .appendSuffix(" months", " months")
    .appendSeparator(" and ")
    .appendDays()
    .appendSuffix(" day", " days")
    .toFormatter();

Log.d("age", dhm.print(g.normalizedStandard()));
```

when I tried this, I got `28 years and 4 months`, but if I tried with `Period g = new Period(a);` I only got `5 days` it supposed to be `28 years and 4 months and 17 days`

Comment: To get the number of days as an `int`, you're going to want to use `nm_days.getDays()`.

Comment: @A--C got it, thank, but I still can't convert days to format years months and days

Comment: Divide days by 365 to get how many years; then do `days % 365` to get the number of days left; etc. If you want to handle leap years, you'll have to do some more complicated logic.

Comment: There is no unique solution. For example 32 days could be 1 month and 1 day (if the month has 31 days) or 1 month and 4 days (if the month has 28 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want [`PeriodFormat.wordBased`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#wordBased%28%29) and [`new Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.PeriodType%29):

```
Period period = new Period(birthdate, now);
Log.d("age", PeriodFormat.wordBased().print(period));
```

> age: 28 years, 4 months and 17 days

Normally, this would pick up your locale, or you could explicitly pass a locale to [`PeriodFormat.wordBased`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#wordBased%28java.util.Locale%29). Unfortunately, Joda doesn't seem to be localized for Indonesia. You can either make your own formatter, as in your question, or (if you have more time available, want a good CV item, etc.) look into making an Indonesian localization for Joda.

Comment: it's great, but can I set it so there is no '-' ? I would prefer 4 months and 29 days rather than 5 months and -1 days, and can I change it to my language? I'm Indonesian